# how to not call function of viewdid appear methods while came back from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

1)videovc.swift

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.createTimerView()
    }
```

2)MyvideosVC.swift

```
@objc func btnBackTapping(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

on backtapping i want to hide `createTimerView()` function when `viewDidAppear` method call again, if Anyone can help that would be greatful Thakyou in Advance.

Comment: any reason for `viewDidAppear` you may use `viewDidLoad`

Comment: You can use delegates or completion blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Move it in viewDidLoad and it will be called only on once per creation

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.createTimerView()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, There is concept called ViewController Lifecycle.

`ViewDidLoad` is method which gets called only once in the life cycle of ViewControlller

I would highly recommend you to go through this article:

https://medium.com/good-morning-swift/ios-view-controller-life-cycle-2a0f02e74ff5